# How to check key exist in json or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have JSON object and i want to check key is set in that JSON object

**Here is JSON object**

```
var Data_Array = {
    "Private": {
        "Price": {
            "Adult": "18",
            "Child": [{
                "FromAge": "0",
                "ToAge": "12",
                "Price": "10"
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

**If JSON Object like this as you can see *Child* is not exist, then how to check this**

```
var Data_Array = {
    "Private": {
        "Price": {
            "Adult": "18"
        }
    }
}
```

***I have tried***

```
if(Data_Array.Private.Price.Child[0].Price != "undefined"){
    ...
}
```

**But it is showing me this error**

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property

I am not be able to find out what should i do.

Comment: `Data_Array.Private.Price.hasOwnProperty("Child")`

Comment: FYI: You do *not* have a "JSON object." This is a widespread misnomer. [JSON](http://www.json.org/) stands for "Javascript Object Notation." So any valid JSON is valid Javascript. What you have there is an *object*. JSON is a text format.

Comment: [There is no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: See also [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2904131/218196)

Comment: @MikeC, i agreed your word and i kept it in my mind a big thanks for information.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```js
var json = {key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2'}

"key1" in json ? console.log('key exists') : console.log('unknown key')

"key3" in json ? console.log('key exists') : console.log('unknown key')
```

for child key

```js
var Data_Array = {
    "Private": {
        "Price": {
            "Adult": "18",
            "Child": [{
                "FromAge": "0",
                "ToAge": "12",
                "Price": "10"
            }]
        }
    }
}

'Child' in Data_Array.Private.Price ? console.log('Child detected') : console.log('Child missing')
```

create variable child

```js
var Data_Array = {
    "Private": {
        "Price": {
            "Adult": "18",
            "Child": [{
                "FromAge": "0",
                "ToAge": "12",
                "Price": "10"
            }]
        }
    }
}

var child = 'Child' in Data_Array.Private.Price && Data_Array.Private.Price.Child[0] || 'there is no child'

console.log(child)
```

if there is no child

```js
var Data_Array = {
    "Private": {
        "Price": {
            "Adult": "18"
        }
    }
}

var child = 'Child' in Data_Array.Private.Price && Data_Array.Private.Price.Child[0] || 'there is no child'

console.log(child)
```

Comment: This works fine but could you help me how it works

`var child = 'Child' in Data_Array.Private.Price && Data_Array.Private.Price.Child[0] || 'there is no child'` VS 
`var child = 'Child' in (Data_Array.Private.Price && Data_Array.Private.Price.Child[0]) ? Data_Array.Private.Price.Child[0] : 'there is no child';`

Comment: In expression var a = b && c || d

if b is true, c is returned and d is skipped, so a = c,
or if b is false, c is skipped and d is returned, so a = d

Comment: Great!, Good explanation.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) for an object.

> The **`in`** operator returns `true` if the specified property is in the specified object.

```
if ('Child' in Data_Array.Private.Price) {
    // more code
}
```

Comment: Will throw an exception if `Private` is not a property

Comment: right, but the question was about `Child` to test.

Comment: Just wanted to inform as it seems OP does not understand why those exceptions arise

Answer (score 2):

Trying to get a property off of an object that is not defined will raise an exception. You need to check each property for existence (and type) throughout the chain (unless you are sure of the structure).

Using Lodash:

```
if(_.has(Data_Array, 'Private.Price.Child')) {
    if(Array.isArray(Data_Array.Private.Price.Child) && Data_Array.Private.Price.Child.length && Data_Array.Private.Price.Child[0].Price) {
        // Its has a price!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if Child is undefined

```
if (typeof Data_Array.Private.Price.Child!== "undefined") {
    ...
}
```

Or you can use `in`:

```
if ("Child" in Data_Array.Private.Price) {
    ...
}
```

Or you can use `_.isUndefined(Data_Array.Private.Price.Child)` of underscore.js